# Simplest way to migrate EDMX to EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, migration, edmx

we already a .net application with a heavy edmx (more than 1000 tables and stored procedures...) we want to migrate the dll that contains edmx to .NET Core. What is the simplest way/tool/process to do it? the official video of MS to do that is https://youtu.be/rRhBX2653Sg
but the speaker didn't seem very comfortable to do it in spite of the light edmx of his sample.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you will want to [Scaffold-DbContext](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx) and then modify your VS Project from there, if necessary. With that many tables and columns, I would not suggest doing this by hand/manually.

Comment: One idea (and this is not a complete solution) is to create a new class project and reverse engineer the database using [EFCorePowerTools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki), add in anything from the current project into the new project. When satisfied point to the new class project or if you write unit test run the code against the new project.